# React: setState causes app crash

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and for learning purposes creating now some app, that supposed to show city or any address with react-google-map. The problem is I am not sure how to communicate this data, I am getting with axios tool.

So here is a link - [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HtCcU9qa) . It is one code snippet, but I separated each file with comment. I am using some EventEmitter script to communicate data. The problem is, when I am setting state in google-map js file, it starts endlessly to console.log, doesn`t re-render and crashes the tab.

**Problem Solved. Hope, it might help somebody else as well. Changed Code:**

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loc: {lat: undefined, lng: undefined}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    EventEmitter.subscribe('locationChanged', (data) => { 
      this.setState({loc: data});
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {lat, lng} = this.state.loc;
    var city = [];
    var key = lng + "" + lat;
    city.push(<GoogleMapComponent key={key} lat={lat} lng={lng} />);
    return (
        <div>
          <SearchBar />
          {city}
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

And google_map component I  made stateless:

```
import React from 'react';
import {GoogleMapLoader, GoogleMap} from "react-google-maps";

export default (props) => {
   if(props.lat === undefined) {
      return <div> &nbsp; </div>;
    };

  console.log(props.lat, props.lng);

  return (
    <GoogleMapLoader
      containerElement = { <div style={{ height: '60%' }} /> }
      googleMapElement = {
        <GoogleMap defaultZoom = {12} defaultCenter = {{ lat: props.lat, lng: props.lng }} />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant post *directly* in your post.

Comment: I am sorry. What do you mean by post?

Comment: @FelixKling, do you mean the whole code in the question?

Comment: The relevant code, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're subscribing to your event emitter inside your `render` function, which gets called whenever you set state, which resubscribes, which sets state and calls render which re subscribes and sets state.....

Move this logic up into `componentDidMount` which will subscribe just once.

```
class GoogleMapComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loc: {lat: 50, lng: 40}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    EventEmitter.subscribe('locationChanged', (data) => { 
      this.setState({loc: data});
    });
  }

  render() { .. }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it certainly solves the problem with endless execution, but it doesn`t re-render, even though the state is changed.

Comment: Does it _call_ render? If you put a console log inside `render` does it hit it? Furthermore, is your event emitter callback being hit? is that console log still working?

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe then it is a problem with react-google-map, I should be looking into. Thanks, again.

Comment: I guess make sure your `data` object is formatted properly, but you're right it could be something else.

Comment: now it works. I did the following: I made an array, in which I store the current google map component with certain props and then replace it every time. But seems for me a little bit illogical.

Comment: Can you update your question with your changes? You can probably also erase the code that's not relevant.